# How to show an icon on the screen in Swift application?

Tags: json, swift, image

I wrote a simple application that shows the weather in some city that you may write into the search bar.

The application is getting this information from JSON (the part of JSON request):

```
"current": {
    "condition": {
        "text": "Sunny",
        "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png",
        "code": 1000
    },
    "wind_mph": 4.3,
    "wind_kph": 6.8,
```

Downloading of icon is definitely working because sometimes I see the image, but usually not.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var image = UIImage()
```

The code with assignment to global variables is in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    if errorHasOccured {
        self?.cityLabel.text = "Uncnown city"
        self?.temperatureLabel.text = ""
    } else {
        self?.cityLabel.text = locationName
        self?.temperatureLabel.text = "\(temperature!)"
        self?.imageView.image = image
    }

}
```

How to do this right?

Full code: https://pastebin.com/jbzgQyPN

Comment: It's because your not waiting for the network request to complete before trying to use the image. https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/#data_out

Answer (score 0):

You are set the image in wrong place. Your task in background thread so you need to add image on imageView when response came.

```
        let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: iconURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            // The download has finished.
            if let e = error {
                print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
                print(2)
            } else {
                print(3)
                // No errors found.
                // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
                if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                    if let imageData = data {
                        // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                        image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                       /// ****You have to set the image here***
                        self?.imageView.image = image

                        print(3)
                        // Do something with your image.
                    } else {
                        print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats right, but it should be in the main thread. Thank you.
`DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                                    self?.imageView.image = image
                                }`

Comment: Yes, for updating the UI from the background thread, you can use DispatchQueue.main.sync